# Any readable article that describes the exact benefits and functionality of Microsoft Exchange Server?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, exchange-2007, exchange-2010, tutorial

I'm looking for an article or tutorial (or a couple of them) that would explain Microsoft's Exchange Server and its functionality plainly and with clear examples (what it does? why and when is that functionality needed? etc.), as for a layman if possible. I've looked over Microsoft's website, but it's nothing really specific. It seems that it presents a lot of business terms, but no clear examples or functionality.

I have no previous experience with MS Exchange, but I may be developing for it in the near future, that is why I would like to know what it is capable of and why it is needed within a company.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia has a article about it wich describes alot of what you're asking for:

[Wikipedia: Microsoft Exchange Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Exchange_Server)

A brief list that pops into my head:

- A global address list of all your exchange users plus distribution groups
- Simplified managment through AD, enables more use of SSO
- Calendar sharing (especially useful for sales department etc)
- Room/equipment booking
- Outlook Web Access (wich, as it's titled, a basic Outlook in a web browser with all your mail, contacts, calendars etc)
- ActiveSync (sync mail/calendar/contacts of mobile phones/PDA over the air)

Competitors offer the same, but most AD-heavy organizations turn to Exchange for it's seamless intergration. Exchange 2010 can be installed and up and going within very short amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

...or the [Microsoft Exchange Page](http://www.microsoft.com/exchange).  That is, after all, what it's for...